# About the correctness of a Christoffel-symbol-related equivalence

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus

*Disclaimer*: This question had been asked 10 months ago in [Mathematics SX](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4375835/about-the-correctness-of-a-christoffel-symbol-related-equivalence), but it is still unanswered there.

---

In "Introduction to Tensor Analysis and the Calculus of Moving Surfaces" of Grinfeld, after introducing the Christoffel symbol like

$$\frac{\partial \mathbf{Z}_{i}}{\partial Z^{j}} = \Gamma^{k}_{ij}\mathbf{Z_{k}}~~~(*),$$

the author derives

$$\Gamma^{k}_{ij} = \mathbf{Z^{k}}\cdot \frac{\partial \mathbf{Z}_{i}}{\partial Z^{j}}~~~(**)$$

by dot-producting both sides of (*) by $Z^l$, and relabeling $l$ to $k$.

Then, the books says

> In Euclidean space, equations (*) and (**) are equivalent.

But I don't understand why the author stresses on the correctness of equivalence only in the case of Euclidean space rather than any (including curved) spaces?

Any clarification is very appreciated.

Comment: I think that by "Euclidean space" he means "Riemannian manifold", so a space with Euclidean signature.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux: what do you mean by Euclidean signature?

Comment: I mean that all the metric components are positive.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux: But that still seems like an unnecessary constraint on the generality of the intended equivalence, right?

Comment: In Lorentzian space, the contraction of $Z$ with itself can give $0$, which means the two are equivalent. But it is impossible in a Euclidean-signature space (unless $Z$ is the null vector).